# How to shorten the type names?

Tags: c#, .net

Hey I'm newbie in C# and I'm wrote this piece of code:

```
static void Main()
{
    Dictionary<int, HashSet<string>> dict1 = new Dictionary<int, HashSet<string>>();
    Dictionary<int, HashSet<string>> dict2 = new Dictionary<int, HashSet<string>>();
    // ...
    CompareDicts(dict1, dict2);
}

private static void CompareDicts(Dictionary<int, HashSet<string>> dict1, Dictionary<int, HashSet<string>> dict2)
{
    // Blah blah
}
```

Is there any way to make this code more readable (shorter)?

Comment: Side note: there is nothing particularly unreadable in your sample (except somewhat bad function name - it can't really compare anything because it does not return result, maybe `void EsureDictionariesAreEqual` or `int CompareDicts`). Damian Drygiel provided possible ways to shorten code, but beware of alias - it is hard to come up with good names and aliases are only local to file - so you still will need full type in other places...

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use type [alias](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c3ay4x3d(v=vs.110).aspx) and [var](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb383973.aspx)

```
using AliasName = System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<int, System.Collections.Generic.HashSet<string>>;

namespace Progam1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            var dict1 = new AliasName();
            var dict2 = new AliasName();

            CompareDicts(dict1, dict2);
        }

        private static void CompareDicts(AliasName dict1, AliasName dict2)
        {
            // Blah blah
        }

    }
}
```

But use `var` only if it's clear what kind of data does it contains:

For example,
It's good:

```
var abc = new List<int>();
```

It's bad:

```
var abc = SomeFunc();
```

... because you don't know **instantly** (while reading the code) what type of data `SomeFunc` returns.
You have to move your mouse over `var` to see the type (in Visual Studio).

Comment: For the sake of readability using `var` _only_ would be more appropriate in my opinion. But I did not know that the `using` directive was so powerful +1.

Comment: +1 for `using`... If return type of function is so unclear from its name that you have to explicitly specify type of variable it may mean bad name of the function. I.e. `CompareDicts` is bad name because all other `Compare...` functions return some sort of comparison result instead of `void`...

Comment: The value of `var` in your second case is even greater: you can change the return type of the method without having to change your declaration of `abc`.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes when you're dealing with methods with a lot of parameters and/or parameters with long type names, it can be helpful to format them as more, shorter lines:

```
private static void CompareDicts(
    Dictionary<int, HashSet<string>> dict1,
    Dictionary<int, HashSet<string>> dict2
)
{
    // Blah blah
}
```

This doesn't do anything to address the length of the type names and, technically, your code isn't any shorter now, but I think readability is greatly improved.  For this particular method I might strike a balance between horizontal and vertical screen real estate like this:

```
private static void CompareDicts(
    Dictionary<int, HashSet<string>> dict1, Dictionary<int, HashSet<string>> dict2
)
{
    // Blah blah
}
```

Comment: +1 for code formatting. You can configure preferred line lengths in your [EditorConfig](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/create-portable-custom-editor-options).